# iOS Objective C Programming Xcode using if statements

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I am trying to use if statements in an app to calculate a persons body mass index (BMI).
I needs the user to be able to input either metric or imperial units for weight and height and I would really like to be able to have the user even input metric weight for example, and imperial height.
I thought using an if statement would be best and my code is below. Currently I have warnings on the if statements and it just ignores them. Many thanks to any help.

```
- (IBAction)calculateProcess:(id)sender {
    float cm = [_cmHeight.text floatValue];
    float feet = [_feetHeight.text floatValue];
    float inches = [_inchesHeight.text floatValue];
    float kg = [_kgWeight.text floatValue];
    float stone = [_stoneWeight.text floatValue];
    float pound = [_poundWeight.text floatValue];
    float height;
    float mass;

    if (cm == 0){
        float height = 0.3048*feet + 0.0254*inches;
    } else {
        float height = cm/100;
    }

    if (kg == 0){
        float mass = (6.35029*stone) + (0.453592*pound);
    } else {
        float mass = cm/100;
    }

    float bmi = mass/(height*height);
    [_resultLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", bmi]];
}
```

Comment: You should post the warnings that you're seeing, but one issue I see immediately in the code you've posted is that you write (for example) `float height = ...` inside your `if` and `else` clauses.  That creates a *new* variable, called `height` that prevents the variable `height` defined above the if statements from being modified.  Inside the if and else clauses you should just write: `height = ...` without the `float`.

Comment: I think.. the real question here is.. what is your problem or question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-else blocks redeclare the stack variables `height` and `mass`, so the code after the if-else blocks won't see the conditional results.  Change this way ...

```
// ...
float height;
float mass;

if (cm == 0){
    // see - no float type
    height = 0.3048*feet + 0.0254*inches;
} else {
    height = cm/100;
}

if (kg == 0){
    mass = (6.35029*stone) + (0.453592*pound);
} else {
    mass = cm/100;
}
```

As an aside, both statements can be made more concise like this:

```
height = (cm == 0)? 0.3048*feet + 0.0254*inches : cm/100;
mass = (kg == 0)? (6.35029*stone) + (0.453592*pound) :  cm/100;
```

Comment: I see no benefit in using the ternary operator to make the statements "more concise". Additionally shouldn't the if statements be `if (cm == 0.0f)`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... you mean more concise is not beneficial, or that it isn't more concise?  And, are you suggesting that the ternary clause should be preceded by an "if"?  It shouldn't.

Comment: Oh - I see, you mean the numeric literal in the comparison should be a literal float 0.0 and typed "f".  It's less ambiguous to the reader, but since there's an implicit cast in the expression, it's clear for the compiler and functionally identical.

Comment: Sorry, I just think those expression are too complicated to use a ternary operator and assignment and math all in one line.

Comment: Okay, well thanks very much guys anyway particularly danh. That worked fine. So just for clarification, if I declare a variable within an id statement, can it only remain within the if statement?

Comment: @simbo64, I'd say it this way:  when you declare a variable within a scope (say, a method), it's known throughout that scope.  If you declare it again within that scope (say, a conditional), the new declaration is a new variable by the same name, hiding the original.